# Why does device memory used go up after clearing cache on an app?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, cache, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I would have thought memory used should go down not up. Is there some sort of recycle bin I need to be clearing out somewhere?

Comment: Could you please add a few more details? An example (best with screenshots) would make it much easier to follow. If you cannot include the screenshots, simply mention the URLs to them, and one of us can take care for it.